# Oracle APEX Open Page from a Function

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have my page P2000_Patient.

On this page i have an item P2000_Criteria_id (type: number field).

I want to create a button with dynamic action and based on this value to search my table and if this Criteria_id matches the contents of my table open the page P2002_Symptoms, otherwise open the page P2001_Episodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see there is no need for a dynamic action to fulfil this requirement. Just create a button with action "Submit Page" and handle the logic to redirect to page 2001 or 2002 in a branch. Create 2 branches, one for each page and a serverside condition of "rows returned" for 2002 and "no rows returned" for 2001.

Comment: Thank you Koen Lostrie

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisite is to know the URL syntax
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03017

Then review documentation pages https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aexjs/apex.navigation.html#.fn:dialog

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aexjs/apex.navigation.html#.redirect

Comment: Thank you Enrique Flores